# Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request while submitting form in hosted website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, smtp, sendmail

Recently I published asp.net MVC4 website.when I go to the contact form after submitting all the details it throws `Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request`. How to solve this issue? What is the reason behind this.the contact form is working smoothly in localhost. whenever we submit the form the details send to the mail

Here is my code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(form model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = "";
            TempData["notice"] = "Your form is submitted";
            //write to txt file
            var name = Request["Name"];
            var email = Request["Email"];
            var phone = Request["Phone"];
            var message = Request["Message"];
            var subject = "contact us";
            var userdata = "Name :" + name + "<br/>" + "Email id :" + email + "<br/>" + "Phone Number :" + phone + "<br/>" + "<b/>Message :" + "<br/>" + message;
            //var datafile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.txt");
            //System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@datafile,userdata);
            //result = "information saved";
            var body = userdata;


            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(email.ToString());
            msg.To.Add("mail id here");
            msg.Subject = "Contact Us";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            msg.Body = userdata;

            //smtp settings
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail id", "password");
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
            smtp.Send(msg);



            return RedirectToAction("Contact", "Home");
        }
```

Comment: Please do changes in your web.config file >> <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>   This will show exact error on your web page so you can identify why error is coming.

Comment: it doesn't work for asp.net mvc 4...